# Laravel-horizon not displaying messages from laravel-echo

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I am using laravel-echo and laravel-horizon in my project. Sockets work great. The problem is that I can't see anything in the horizon even though the message for the socket goes through the queue and through redis. Moreover, if I run the conditional TestJob::dispatch, I see this in horizon. In which direction to dig at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the event should implement **ShouldBroadcast** instead of **ShouldBroadcastNow**. Sockets will work either way, but horizon only with **ShouldBroadcast**.